# Launching AngularJS (1.6) app from external application with User Authentication Token

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, integration, session-cookies, auth-token

I am looking forward for any help w.r.t launching my AngularJS (1.6) app from external application (A third party App, most probably will be .NET based) with User Authentication Token. This third party app will do authentication and load list table to Products, when they click details it should launch my app and load details of that Product, So I am looking forward to know how to pass ProductID, User Auth Token (or any other way maybe session cookies)

Comment: You should try something out first and be more specific because your question is both _unclear_ and _too broad_. It sounds like some standard web application that consumes a third party API. You can go old school like Paypal if you want ideas on patterns for inspiration. Web site of products -> authenticates to Paypal API -> gets a token -> and goes from there.